# ScalaDoc with Futures

Tags: future, scaladoc

So is there any correct way to annotate futures in scaladoc (specifically failures)? `@throws` doesn't seem appropriate since the exceptions get wrapped in a `Try` (`Failure`). Was looking for something like a `@failure` tag.

```
/**
 * @failure FooException If i is even
 * @failure BarException If i is odd
 */
def foo(i: Int) = Future {
   i match {
      case i if i % 2 == 0 => throw new FooException()
      case _ => throw new BarException()
   }
}
```